# Why is data not being refreshed in StreamBuilder?

Tags: api, flutter, movies, stream-builder

I am making a movie list application in Flutter and when I open the app I am displaying most-viewed movies list. When I click a button, I fetch new data and add it to the sink which is then sent to the StreamBuilder and should refresh the screen with new data.
But that doesn't happen. I cannot fathom why!

Here is my code for the Repository:

```
class MoviesRepository {
  final _movieApiProvider = MovieApiProvider();

  fetchAllMovies() async => _movieApiProvider.fetchMovieList();

  fetchAllSimilarMovies(genreIdeas) async => await _movieApiProvider.fetchMoviesLikeThis(genreIdeas);

  fetchTopRatedMovies() async => await _movieApiProvider.fetchTopRatedMovieList();
}
```

Here is my code for bloc:

```
class MoviesBloc {

  final _moviesRepository = MoviesRepository();
  final _moviesFetcher = BehaviorSubject<Result>();

  Sink<Result> get allMovies => _fetcherController.sink;
  final _fetcherController = StreamController<Result>();

  Observable<Result> get newResults => _moviesFetcher.stream;

  fetchAllMovies() async {
    Result model = await _moviesRepository.fetchAllMovies();
    allMovies.add(model);
  }

  fetchTopRatedMovies() async{
    Result model = await _moviesRepository.fetchTopRatedMovies();
    allMovies.add(model);
  }

  dispose() {
    _moviesFetcher.close();
    _fetcherController.close();
  }

  MoviesBloc() {
    _fetcherController.stream.listen(_handle);
  }


  void _handle(Result event) {

    _moviesFetcher.add(event);

  }
}

final bloc = MoviesBloc();
```

**UPDATE**

And here is my code for the StreamBuilder:

```
class HomeScreenListState extends State<HomeScreenList> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    print("init");
    bloc.fetchAllMovies();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    bloc.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder<Result>(
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasData) {
          print("new data is here");
          return buildList(snapshot);
        } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
          return Text('Error!!');
        }

        return Center(
          child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
        );
      },
      stream: bloc.newResults,
    );
  }
}
```

And this is the button that triggers to get new data and add it to the sink:

```
child: RaisedButton(onPressed: () {
                    bloc.fetchTopRatedMovies();
                  },
```

This button fetches top-rated movies and add to the same sink. Now the StreamBuilder should pick up the new data as I think.

Where is the problem??

Comment: Which part is not working? Is the new result added to the `allMovies` sink? Does `_handle` get called? The code looks like it should work as far as I can tell.

Comment: @Edman Sorry for such a late reply, but after a lot of debugging, allMovies sink does get called. And the _handle is called too.
Widget rebuilding does not take place. I have updated the last part of the code to add logs whenever widget is built but that is only called once when the app launches.

Comment: @Dhruvam Sharma i am following the same example as u but in my case the streambuilder snapshot has no data(not null) any suggestions?

Comment: @Lekr0 I suggest that you use BehaviourSubject instead of Stream Controller. It will make your task easier.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Equatable](https://pub.dev/packages/equatable) alongside your BLoC implementation to manage state changes on your screen. Here's a [guide](https://betterprogramming.pub/simplifying-bloc-state-management-in-flutter-a8de43a994e4) that I suggest trying out.